A doubt in second fundamental theorem of calculus.
Question
I am trying to find an example of a function $P$ such that it satisfies $P^{'} = f$ and $f$ is discontinuous. So, the second fundamental theorem of calculus isn't satisfied, so the following doesn't hold true: $\int_{c}^{x}f(x)dx = P(x)-P(c)$ in the example chosen.
Similar
It was fairly easy to construct example of such a function $f$ such that if $F(x)  = \int_{c}^{x}f(x)dx$, then $F^{'}(c) \ne f(c)$ for some $c$. But I don't have any idea how to find $P$ such that $P^{'} = f$

@LeeMosher I am not trying to conclude that it  $\int_{c}^{x}f(x)dx = P(x)-P(c)$ is false for all cases where $f$ is discontinuous. But trying to find one specific example where it doesn't hold. If it holds for all cases, we won't even need the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous.

@LeeMosher Thanks a lot.

@ThomasAndrews Nope. That doesn't work. I tried that. If you could write and show why should that example work, I would be grateful. It is an example of something else, that $f^{'}$ is discontinuous but didn't work here. In this case actually it holds that $\int_{c}^{x} = f(x)-f(c)$ despite $f^{'}$ being discontinuous at $0$.

What doesn't work about it? It definitely has a discontinuous derivative, and that is all you asked for, as the question current stands. @Debu

@ThomasAndrews I modified the question to make it clearer.

The statement on Wikipedia requires only that $P'$ be Riemann integrable, which is weaker than continuous, and is clearly required since otherwise $\int_a^x P'(t),dt$ is undefined.

An example will be $|x|^{3/2}\sin(1/x),$ because the derivative is unbounded near zero.

(Timing interleaved with Thomas's (+1) comments.) If $P' = f$ is integrable with an isolated discontinuity at $c$, then $\int_c^x f = P(x)-P(c)$ by standard arguments. (Call the integral $F(x)$, use the other FTC to deduce $F'=f=P'$ away from $c$, apply the identity theorem and continuity of $F$.) <> Consequently, it looks to me that you need to seek a differentiable function whose derivative is not integrable, e.g., is unbounded, so the stated equation fails because the left-hand side isn't sensible.

Often, intro books won't prove the strongest theorem, so, while your book requires $P'$ continuous, that is not as strong as they can make, it just might take more work and preparation to prove the stronger result.

Actually, the example I gave has only one discontinuity for $P',$ but $P'$ is unbounded near $0$ so not Riemann integrable. @AndrewD.Hwang

@ThomasAndrews I agree that the core issue is (non-)integrability of $P'$. My comment to OP was directed at what seemed to be a presumption that if $P' = f$ is integrable but discontinuous at $c$, we might have $P'(c) \neq f(c)$, and that such a counterexample should be sought. (Tangentially, Bowei's deleted answer looks good; the point there also is $f$ is unbounded at $0$....)

Given $1<\alpha<2 $ let $P(x)=|x|^\alpha \sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $P(0)=0,$ then $P'(x)$ exists for all $x,$ For positive $x,$ the derivative is $$P'(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}\sin(1/x)+\frac1{x^{2-\alpha}}\cos(1/x).$$
This function is unbounded near $0,$ and hence not Riemann integrable around $0.$
This is because the left term of $P'$ is bounded near $0$ since $\alpha>1$ and the right term can get arbitrarily large for $\alpha<2,$ by picking $x=\frac1{2\pi n}$ so the cosine term is $1.$
Not sure if you can "fix" this with, say, Lebesgue integral, where unbounded functions can have integrals. But Riemann integrals require bounded functions.
